# Need to echo a statement if all the conditions are true in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file temp.txt with the below content

```
NORMAL
NORMAL
NORMAL
NORMAL
```

```sh
tab=$(cat temp.txt)
for state in $tab
do
    if [ "$state" = "NORMAL" ]; then
        :
    else
        echo "$state"
    fi
done
```

I need the output if all the states are NORMAL it should print a single statement "All are Normal".

Suppose if one of the state is NOT_NORMAL it should just print the NOT_NORMAL state .

Comment: Please edit your post and wrap your samples in CODE TAGS.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have wrapped them with code tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are ok with `awk` try following.

```
awk '
$0=="NORMAL"{
  count++
  val=FNR
}
END{
  if(val==count){
     print "All are Normal."
  }
  else{
     print "NOT_NORMAL"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
if ! grep -v '^NORMAL$' temp.txt >&2; then
    echo All are Normal
fi
```

The grep will print all the non-normal messages for you.  Note that any blank line will be taken as a failure state, so you may need want to prefilter the data.  Also, I presume you would want non-normal states to be written to stderr, but perhaps you'll want to remove the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i m not the linux expert but i think something like this will work for you.

```
tab=$(cat temp.txt)
for state in $tab
do
#when state is not normal
   if [ $state != "NORMAL" ]; then
   #exit the loop or the programm   exit(1),..
     exit(9) 
   else
   #state is normal, so we check the next state
    continue
   fi
   #all state are normal
   echo "$state"
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple grep :

```
not_normal_text="NOT_NORMAL"
if grep -q "$not_normal_text" temp.txt
then 
    echo "$not_normal_text" text found  
else  
    echo "ALL NORMAL"
fi
```

Note that this will only look for "NOT_NORMAL" lines. 
An alternative way reading line by line, will output BAD if any line is not "NORMAL", and no output otherwise :

```
while read line; do if [ ! "$line" = "NORMAL" ]; then echo "BAD"; break; fi; done < temp.txt
```